MAUI IOS provisioning profile not found
I have a dotnet 8 MAUI IOS app. This is not an xcode project. I have a IOS App Development Provisioning Profile called "TIMS Testing" that is tied to an IOS Development certificate. Both were created today. I have downloaded both to my Mac. In Keychain I can see the cert and it is verified. I can also see it in xcode.
When I attempt to run the app on my physical testing device I get this error:
dotnet build -t:Run -f net8.0-ios -p:_DeviceName=00008110-001838D634D9801E
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8020/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(1834,3): error : Could not find any available provisioning profiles for TIMS on iOS. [/Users/user/Projects/cds-tims-mobile-client/TIMS.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8020/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(1834,3): error :          [/Users/user/Projects/cds-tims-mobile-client/TIMS.csproj]

Build FAILED.

/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8020/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(1834,3): error : Could not find any available provisioning profiles for TIMS on iOS.[/Users/user/Projects/cds-tims-mobile-client/TIMS.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8020/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(1834,3): error :          [/Users/user/Projects/cds-tims-mobile-client/TIMS.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)


This is my csproj file:
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
      <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>

       <CodesignProvision>Automatic</CodesignProvision>
      <CodesignKey>iPhone Developer: Cole Perry (T27KR8XA74)</CodesignKey>

      <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
      <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
      <MtouchLink>None</MtouchLink> <!-- No linking for Debug builds -->
      <MtouchDebug>true</MtouchDebug> <!-- Enables debug mode -->
      <MtouchUseLlvm>false</MtouchUseLlvm> <!-- Disables LLVM to avoid inlining issues -->
      <UseNativeHttpHandler>false</UseNativeHttpHandler>
      <SelfContained>false</SelfContained> 
    </PropertyGroup>

All of my other apps provisioning profiles and certs are working correctly, this is the only provisioning profile I am having trouble with. I really am not sure what to do to debug this from here.
How can I check that the Provisioning Profile is properly installed on my machine? What else could I be missing that I might need? Any help greatly appreciated.
Pic of Prov profile if it helps:


First, it's recommended to deploy the project to your phone through automatic provisioning, which doesn't require you to manually create a configuration file, you can refer to the Automatic provisioning for iOS apps.
Also, if you choose to create the configuration file manually, you need to make sure that the App ID of the configuration file is the same as the Bundle identifier in the project's info.plist file. And you need to download the preconfigured configuration file in Visual Studio after creating it.

Thank you for the info. I took your advice and updated my question to reflect this. However it did not improve my situation. I updated the error message, which is basically the same.

What device are you running the project on, Windows or Mac? If it's Windows, you can view the downloaded configuration file at C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning\Profiles,

Hey so I found the solution although it didn't exactly answer my question. I just went back to using the Distribution certificate I had been using and made a new Ad Hoc provisioning profile and that is what I am using. It worked from there.
